# atof changing values of global array

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have an issue that I'm basically baffled by. To start off, I have two global arrays - trustArray[] and fashionArray[]. Here is the function that fills the trustArray:

```
void getTrust()
{
    string line;
    int reachedTrust=0;
    int numberOfTrustsRecorded=0;
    ifstream myfile ("BuyingJeans.Hw5 (1).csv");
    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        while ( myfile.good() )
        {
            getline (myfile,line,',');
            //int found=line.find("Like-Purchase");
            if (line=="Trust-Like"){
                reachedTrust=1;
                getline (myfile,line,',');
            }
            if(reachedTrust==1){
                if(numberOfTrustsRecorded <6){
                    double testValue = atof(line.c_str());
                    trustArray[numberOfTrustsRecorded] = testValue;
                    numberOfTrustsRecorded++;
                }
            }
        }
        myfile.close();
    }
    else
        cout << "Unable to open file"; 
}
```

For some reason, the `atof()` in this function is changing two of the values in fashionArray[]. If I change the `atof()` to say, an `atoi()`, the problem no longer occurs. Here is the method that fills the array that is being changed (fashionArray[]):

```
void getFashion(){
string line;
int reachedFashion=0;
int numberOfFashionsRecorded=0;
ifstream myfile ("BuyingJeans.Hw5 (1).csv");
if (myfile.is_open())
{
    while ( myfile.good() )
    {
        getline (myfile,line,',');
        if (line=="Like-Fash -->"){
            reachedFashion=1;
            getline (myfile,line,',');
            //cout<<line<<endl;
            //getchar();
        }
        if(reachedFashion==1){
            if(numberOfFashionsRecorded <6){
                fashionArray[numberOfFashionsRecorded] = atoi(line.c_str());
                numberOfFashionsRecorded++;
            }
        }

    }
    myfile.close();
}

else cout << "Unable to open file";
```

}

Here is the main method that calls these two methods:

```
int main () {

getFashion();
getTrust();

for(int x=0; x<6;x++)
    cout<<fashionArray[x]<<endl;
getchar();
return 0;
}
```

The first two values of fashionArray end up being changed to some ridiculously large negative and positive integers. One interesting thing is that if I reverse the order in which the two methods are called in the main() method, the issue no longer occurs. Anyone have any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: Where is trustArray declared and allocated?

Comment: Rediculously large negative and positive values sounds exactly like `atof()` failing to convert the C string (value is out of range thus +/- HUGE_VAL is returned)...

Comment: trustArray is declared and allocated globally, same as the array that is being changed. I agree with the value out of range explanation, but I am still confused as to why that would cause values of a DIFFERENT array to be changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are writing beyond `trustArray` and into `fashionArray`. You have not provided initialisation code (please do), but I suppose it looks something like this :

```
float trustArray[N];
float fashionArray[N];
```

With N equal to some positive integer. My guess is that in your case, `N=5`.

In your loop, you test that `numberOfTrustsRecorded < 6`. Values of `numberOfTrustsRecorded` that will pass that test are 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. That's six (6) floats to fit in a array of 5. Writing `numberOfTrustRecorded[5]` will overwrite memory. Change your test or increase your buffer size to 6.

Why aren't you seeing valid values in fashionArray[0] ? I don't know. Maybe your compiler aligned the fashionArray memory buffer so the overwrite starts in unused memory, leaving you with half the bits required to make a IEEE float. Whatever bits are in memory make up a random float. A memory dump would show the problem.

Why is running the method in reverse order works ? Probably that the bug is still there, but running `getFashion()` second cleans the mess left by `getTrust()`. The memory you overwrite is yours, so as long as you don't try to make sense of it, nobody complains. Initialize `fashionArray[0] = 0.0`, run `getTrust()` and look at `fashionArray[0]` before running `getFashion()`. You will probably see the random floats.

Comment: Nice man. Rookie mistake on my part - I did have an array of size 5, not 6.